# Regex to remove duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, vertica

I have a String coming in like this -

```
ABC;ABC;XYZ;PQR;ABC;PQR
```

And requirement is to convert this to something like this -

```
ABC;XYZ;PQR
```

Meaning a Regex should keep all Unique words and remove duplicates. Can anyone please help me with this. Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Fix your data structure.  Storing values in string lists is not the SQLish way to store things.

Comment: (1) what Database Access Language you are using (2) which database -> MySQL or

Comment: (1) Are you using PHP or what>

Comment: I'm on HP Vertica. I wrote a piece but its not working as expected-
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC;PQR;ABC','^(.+?)\;\1*$','\1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [HP Vertica uses PCRE regex](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/RegularExpressionFunctions.htm), the following regex (with null replacement) should work:

```
(?<=\;|^)(.+?)\;(?=(.+\;)?\1(\;|$))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxR5oe/1).

Followe a brief explanation:

- `(?<=\;|^)` is a positive lookbehind meaning that `(.+?)\;` to remove should be preceded by a semicolon or the begin of string
- `(.+?)` is the first capturing group
- `(?=)` is a positive lookahead containing:

  - `(.+\;)?` any other character (ending with a semicolon)
  - `\1` backreference for the first capturing group
  - `(\;|$)` must end with semicolon or EOL

Answer (score -1):

With T-Sql you could do:

```
    DECLARE @Strings NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Strings = '';
    SELECT @Strings = CASE WHEN @Strings != '' THEN @Strings + ';' + [String] ELSE [String] END
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT VALUE AS [String] FROM STRING_SPLIT( 'ABC;ABC;XYZ;PQR;ABC;PQR',';')
    ) AS [Strings]; 
    SELECT @Strings
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but T SQL is not in option. I want to achieve it from a Regex if possible.